# magento2 widget collection sort by array

Tags: magento2

I have a custom widget and in the phtml file I get the product collection through the method `$collection = $block->getProductCollection();`

To sort that collection according to an array containing the skus I use the following code:

```
$productIds = implode (", ", $productIdsarray);
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("
    if (FIELD (`e`.`sku`, {$productIds}) = 0,1,0), 
    FIELD (` e`.`sku`, {$productIds})"
 ));
```

but when I get the items in the collection

```
$items2 = $collection->getItems();
foreach ($items2 as $_item2) {
    echo $_item2->getSku(). ":" . $_item2->getName(). "->".
        . $_item2->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
        . "<br/>";
}
```

They do not come with the order that I have suggested. I think that when you get the items you call the `getProductCollection()` method again and that's why you don't respect the order.

How can it be solved?

Thank you